# How can I configure TFS to build and deploy multiple web applications?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, msbuild

I have a solution that currently has about 20 class libraries, and a dozen different web apps.    Each web app shares a site-wide master page, as well as share js and css files.

I need to be able to build & deploy one app at a time, or occasionally update the entire suite.  How is this possible with TFS and MSDeploy?

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework has lots of improvements about Web deployment.
You can check scott gu's blog for futher information.

But if you situation doesn't fit build-in solutions you can customize your build workflow to copy files from TeamBuildAgent\Binaries folder to target folder.